# aws lambda authorizer function, jsonwebtoken error "Invalid Token", using Bearer before and splicing it

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, token, lambda-authorizer

Im using Lambda Authorizer in AWS and JsonWebToken to pass the token in the headers in Api Gateway. This is my code.

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
  const secret = "sof-admin-token";
  let auth = "Deny";
  const bearer = event["adminToken"];
  if(bearer){
    console.log(bearer)
    const token = bearer.split(" ")[1];
    console.log(token)
    let decoded = await jwt.verify(token, secret); // <- HERE IS THE ERROR (verifying the token)
    console.log(decoded)
    const command = new GetCommand({
      TableName: "sof-admin-db",
      Key: {
        email: decoded.data
      }
    });
    const response = await docClient.send(command);
    if(response.Item && response.Item.role.indexOf("admin")>=0){
      auth = "Allow"
    }
  }
  console.log(auth)
```

After verify the token, I search in the database if is a admin user and then return the authorization or not.

This is the console.log and the token is correct.

```
INFO    eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2O…0MDR9.UiuZk8SkhVNYxOm1uo3HZhWqMQTsamA_F-6lk-eEh3M
ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"JsonWebTokenError","errorMessage":"invalid token"
```

I tried send the token without the bearer with the same results.

Comment: It's difficult to say as the token you pasted is (understandably) not valid.  Have you checked the token with something like https://jwt.io?

Comment: The function works when I pass the token inside the body of the HTTP request. But if I pass the token in the header, throw me the error.
When I paste the token in jwt.io after it passed in the HEADER shows me error.
When I paste the token in jwt.io after it passed in the BODY works fine.
Is like if AWS cut the token in the header but not in the body. Very rare..